# How to update a column and add values: SQLserver

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm doing an update to a SQLserver database. I want to record the number of daily visits. but when the update is done, the visits are not added, they are replaced.
MY CODE:

```
namespace System
{
    class Day
    {
        SqlConnection conect= new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=db_system; Integrated Security=true;");

        public void update_day(string value1, string value2)
        {

            SqlCommand cdm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Visit SET day=  '" + Value1+ "' '" + Value2+ "' ' WHERE user='" + user1+ "' ", conect);

            SqlDataReader myReader;

            conect.Open();
            myReader = cdm.ExecuteReader();
            conect.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Saved");

        }

    }
}
```

I want to add the value2, to the day column of my database.

SAMPLE:

...................TABLE day..........................

column: Visit (10) + Value2

Result:

column: Visit (11) + Value2

I need to add both values

value1 + value2 = 2
in the SqlCommand

I'm waiting for your help Friends, thanks.

Comment: Did you miss any operator between `Value1+ "' '" + Value2`

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: I think you don't know how to update multiple columns ?

Comment: The Operator "+" does not work for me to add the value, as in other databases.

Comment: Value1 + "''" + Value2 I need to add them   sample value1  + value2 = 2

Comment: Can you add DDL, sample data and some expected results to your question?  As it is, it is very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't work out what value1 and value2 are supposed to be in your question. If one is the days to increment, then would the other need to be the userID (as you have the original number of days in the table already)?

If so, could you just add the new value to the existing total like the below?:

```
public void update_day(string userID, string dayIncrement)
    {

        SqlCommand cdm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Visit SET day = day + " + dayIncrement + " WHERE user='" + userID + "' ", conect);
```

etc.

Comment: Brother, you are a Genius!
He served perfectly. my values ​​were added and saved Perfectly. also change the value of nvarchar by int in the database and save it.

I thank you brother.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ADD new rows you should use an [INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement. The [UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement is used to update existing data.

And you desperately need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. Building up a string and executing it like that is wide open to sql injection. Don't do it that way. My friend [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) loves code like that.

--EDIT--

A complete shot in the dark since we have next to nothing in the way of details.

```
Update YourTable
Set IntCol1 = @Int1
    , IntCol2 = @Int2
where SomeKeyColumn = @KeyValue
```

Comment: Hello Friend, thank you very much for the response.
but I do not want an insert. the values ​​already exist. what I want is to update the existing values. regards

Comment: In your question you stated "when the update is done, the visits are not added, they are replaced". Which is it? Do you want to add new rows or update existing ones? Either way the information is in my answer.

Comment: You help me to make the correct query to send them to the database. There is something wrong with my code. the values ​​do not add to the existing ones, I want a visit counter

Comment: Well that makes no sense at all. Remember we can't see your screen and have no idea what your table design is. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: friend I just need a SqlCommand, suitable for adding two (INT or DOUBLE) in a field of a Table.

Comment: Well in your example you have two strings and you sticking the concatenated values into a single column. This is a painfully easy thing to answer if you would trouble yourself to post details that have been asked for by myself and others.